# Tensorflow: global_step values does not change (always 0)

Tags: tensorflow

I created global_step variable through get_or_create_global_step and later access it with get_global_step, I saw during training the value I accessed did not change at all. Below is the related codes

```
with tf.device(self.device):
    ...
    loss = model.loss(....)
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
    update = model.update(loss, global_step, self.lrate, self.grad_clip)
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    ...

with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=self.server.target, is_chief=(self.task_index == 0), config=config, hooks=hooks) as mon_sess:
    mon_sess.run(init_op)
    _, lossVal, step = mon_sess.run([update, loss, tf.train.get_global_step()])
    print('step %d, train loss = %f' % (step, lossVal))
    ...
```

and model is an instance of Model class with update function implemented as below

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__():
    ...
    def update(self, loss, global_step, learning_rate, grad_clip):
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=loss)
        ...
        update_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=clipped_grads_and_vars,global_step=global_step, name='apply_gradients')
        return update_op
```

above codes print out

```
step 0, train loss = ...
step 0, train loss = ...
step 0, train loss = ...
```

anyone can help on this?

thanks!

Comment: Are you accidentally calling init_op every time? I ask because i don't see a loop in your code.

Comment: yes you are guessing right. such silly mistake from me. thanks a lot suharshs!